# Desktop Apps not connect to internet with VPN in win 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn, proxy, desktop

I can use browsers with VPN but other desktop apps do not connect to VPN when I run VPN as Psiphon. 
I have win 10, 64 bit.

I know I can connect to the internet when I run VPN software but Desktop Apps such as iTunes not use VPN to connect to the internet. when I had windows 7 it worked with no problem.

I have same problem in using proxy servers

Comment: sorry for bad English.

Comment: I don't set up anything, free VPN apps like Psiphon and Hotspot Shield Vpn get connected by one button, I use browsers like firefox and chrome. I know I can connect to the internet when I run VPN software but Desktop Apps such as iTunes not use VPN to connecting internet. when I had windows 7 it worked with no problem.